# deploy django on apache : static files 404 not found

Tags: python, django, apache, http-status-code-404

I deploy my django with Apache
But it can't read the static file
It will cause

> 404 not found

```
static
    |----static
    |       |----css
    |       |----img    
    |       |----js
    |     
    |----static-only
    |       |---css
            |---admin
```

Here is my static structure :

Here is my Django project  `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static-only")
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","media")
STATICFILES_DIRS=(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static"),)
```

apache setting:

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf`

```
Alias /static /home/openuser/tryDjango/static

<Directory /home/openuser/tryDjango/static>
       Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/openuser/tryDjango/src/tryDjango>
       <Files wsgi.py>
               Require all granted
       </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess testproject python-path=/home/openuser/tryDjango/src:/home/openuser/tryDjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup testproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/openuser/tryDjango/src/tryDjango/wsgi.py
```

I found that if I use :

```
Alias /static/static_only /home/openuser/tryDjango/static/static_only
```

files under `static-only` can read

But this still have problem visit:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS=(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static"),)
```

Comment: Have you run `manage.py collectstatic` on deploy?

Comment: have you made a manage.py collectstatic ?

Comment: great! after manage.py collectstatic. It works. And all static files will be collected under ````static_only````